# Float precision problem in metal shading language

Tags: ios, swift, precision, metal, shading

I pass a float param with value 0.00291545 to fragment shader.
But fragment function got n/a.

[swift code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Ufd.png)

[fragment shader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v86pY.png)

In Xcode debugger's "Bound Resources" view, it shows that the value is 0.003

[Bound Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5z74.png)

In Xcode shader debugger view, I made some tests. It shows that 0.0004 will be cast to 0 and 0.0005 will be casted to 0.001. The float value behaves like half value.

[test code in shader debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZl49.png)

So, my question is:

1. Why 0.00291545 is first casted to 0.003, then casted to 0 ?
2. Why float value has the same precision with half ?
3. How could I use float value that has normal precision ?

Comment: Please post textual information (like source code) **as text**, not screenshots of text. Also, don't rely on the display of floating-point numbers by the debugger. It will generally round to just a limited number of significant digits to keep the display compact. That **does not** mean that the value was rounded in actuality, just in display. Make a test that actually checks the value in terms of the rendering result. Like draw all pixels green if the value is between 0.00291 and 0.00292 or red otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was!

Xcode debugger misled me.

0.00291545 was not casted to 0.003 and was not casted to n/a. The debugger' display is not accurate， but the value is accurate actually.

Thanks for  Ken Thomases